# I can't set up default speaker [Win 8.1]

Tags: audio, windows-8.1, speakers, headphones

I couldn't find a question that matched my problem here, so if ther is already solution here, sorry for opening new thread.

I baught recntly new stationary computer with windows 8.1 and one of the biggest problems I have encountered with it, is inability to use my speakers when using headphones. Both are using the analog mini-jack and my computer has two ports for them on the front and on the back. Unfortunatly, when I have connected both it turned out, that I can't use my speakers while having headphones connected to 2nd port. So I tried to switch then and still my headphones where working, but not my spekers. Only after disconecting headphones did my speakers finaly play. So after I thought, that maybe I just need to change the default playbach device and opened the manager window.

To my shock, I have discovered, that my system treats my headphones and speakers as one device, connected to two ports simultaneously, instead of 2 different divices. However, I could not change the setting and I have not yet succeeded in adding either as different device. The only way I can listen to anything through my speakers [when connected to either of jacks ports] is to disconnect headphones, but that is highly annoying, since I specifficly wanted computer with 2 audio ports, so that I wouldn't have to constantly connect and disconnect my audio devices. What can I do to fix this mess?

Comment: Welcome to SU. Sadly this is the case with most Desktops (at least I've ever come across which quite a few) the front Jack is purely for that purpose; to cut off the back Jack and redirect the audio source to itself, then like you say unplugging this allows the back Jack to be used again. I think you will find its by design, if you provide the make and model I can do some more research on your specific PC.

Comment: this is common in PCs, especially laptops. Unfortunately, it is a "feature" intended to be this way.

Comment: @CharlesH: Oh, I see... Well, thanks for answer. Seems just odd, because I had a desktop in past and hadn't got this problem then, though I got one when WinXP was still a young system, that got mixed reviews. As for a model of PC it is not possible for me to write it, because it has been custom made and the only thing I can check, is each individual part.

Comment: Generally, people use headphones when they don't want sound to come from the speakers, so the jacks are designed to function that way.  The rear connection is intended for speakers and the front connection is intended for headphones.

Comment: @Lynx No worries. Custom made, does that mean you used the Audio out port on the motherboard to connect the front Jack's on the case? If that is how its connected then its even more likely to cut off the back ports when it detects the front ports being used. I can see benefits of both. Out of interest did you get a CD to install drivers with the motherboard if so you may have a control panel for the sound card on there which could (unlikely but worth looking) control how this function works.

Comment: @CharlesH: Well, when I said custom made, I meant more that it was made from indyvidual parts for some gamer, but dude canceled his order and the shop was left with a ready product. Since my Laptop crashed completely and this time around I wanted to have a PC which I could also use to play games I just went there and it was the only PC they had ready to go. I propably do have CDs you're talking about, but I already had put the box after computer in the storage room [I had way too many problems with Win 8.1 to even start playing].

Comment: Also, I only know, that it is working on NVIDA drivers and I have Realtek HD audio, but I only ever saw it on my bros computer [he never uses his speakers anyway, so I don't know whether he has the same problems or not], so I do not have any idea about what it is supposed to do. My previous computer was, as I said, a laptop, where I had a Vista and the Realtek was not there.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, this is by design for most sound devices (though it doesn't work on all of them as judged by the myriad questions on SU about how to disable the effect you are seeking).  It is similar to how a laptop or cell phone cuts off the internal speakers whenever headphones are plugged in.

There are a few possible solutions, depending on your specific sound card and how you want to use this.

1. Some soundcards have separate plugs for **headphones** and **line out** (intended to go to an amp/speakers).  If you are lucky enough to have this setup, you may be able to just plug your speakers into the **line out** and your headphones into the **headphone** port.
2. You may be able to find an alternate driver for your card which will allow treating the front and rear ports separately.  This is going to be very dependent on your sound card and the community of users who have the same card/chipset.
3. If you always want the same sound source coming from headphones and speakers (i.e., you leave the headphones on all the time and just turn off the speakers when switching to headphones) then a fix could be simply to get an audio splitter (Y-cable, etc).  These are relatively cheap and can be found at most stores which carry electronics, or online just about anywhere (eBay, etc).
4. If you want to be able to do different sounds through headphones vs. speakers, such as music in the speakers while simultaneously gaming on the headphones, you will need two audio sources.  If you can't find a driver to enable the separation of ports in your specific sound card, you may want to invest in a 2nd sound card.  This can be as simple as a USB device to plug in the headphones.  When the headphone port on my father-in-law's laptop broke, I used [a device like this](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA4V21HR8065&cm_re=usb_sound_card-_-9SIA4V21HR8065-_-Product) to replace it and it worked well.